# delete millions of records that has a duplicate column values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Want to delete millions of records that has a duplicate column values , and if found duplicates then both rows are deleted.

like if first row has column value as abcv and found another row lets say 10th row with same value, then in that case delete both rows where I found abcv.

I am trying with

```
Delete from TABLE where column in(1,2,3,4,6,9)
```

But the above query dont suits my case here as I have a very long string in IN clause.

I need to perform this with millions of records .

Comment: @Saty I assume thats a joke! That should certainly solve this problem, all he would then need to do is restore this table from his last backup. _backups... hahahhahaha_

Comment: Ahhh using my suggestion the whole table record is deleted !!! @RiggsFolly thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: if several rows share a particular column value, do you want to delete them *all*? I think that's what you said.

First, you need to find the rows with duplicate values.  That works with a subquery like this.

```
              SELECT * 
                FROM table
               WHERE colval_with_duplicates IN (
                         SELECT colval_with_duplicates
                           FROM table
                          GROUP BY colval_with_duplicates
                         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
               ORDER BY colval ,id
```

You should test this subquery before you move forward with using it to delete stuff.  Why? Because I'm not yet sure I understand your requirement. This subquery shows the rows that will be deleted.

Then you want to use a version of this subquery in a DELETE query, like this.

```
 DELETE FROM TABLE
  WHERE id IN (
              SELECT id 
                FROM table
               WHERE colval_with_duplicates IN (
                         SELECT colval_with_duplicates
                           FROM table
                          GROUP BY colval_with_duplicates
                         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
               LIMIT 1000
              )
```

You have a big table, so you want to do your deleting in batches rather than all at once.  If you try to do it all at once, you may blow out your transaction log space, and it will take a long time. The `LIMIT 1000` will do batches of one thousand duplicate key values at a time. You simply repeat this `DELETE` query until it affects no rows, and you are done.

Make sure you do batches of duplicate column values, not batches of ID values.

Comment: I was just going to ask about that, I was going to suggest `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` rather that 2. And I was going to ask why you used `> 2`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right, it was just a typo. I fixed it.  `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and `HAVING COUNT(*) >=2` are both valid ways of choosing the duplicates.

Comment: I was not complaining, was half way through a very similiar answer when I saw yours posted, hence the upvote. I was just interested, I thought maybe I was missing something, so I asked purely for my personal edification.

Answer (score 0):

```
Where
 - TableName is 'Employee' Assumed.
 - 'id' is a column (having primary key and Auto increment, which is mainly ist column of table)
 - 'stud_id' is a column name having duplicate values.

So, change accordingly the column name and table name.

 - It will delete all duplicate values.
        DELETE T1,T2 FROM Employee T1, Employee T2 
        WHERE T1.id > T2.id AND T1.stud_id = T2.stud_id

 - It WIll Delete one duplicate values from column
       DELETE T1 FROM Employee T1, Employee T2 
       WHERE T1.id > T2.id AND T1.stud_id = T2.stud_id
```

For more info, check this [Delete Duplicate Data From Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205067/how-to-delete-if-the-data-is-duplicate/32205823#32205823) Link.

Answer (score -1):

add a UNIQUE index on the columns. When you write the ALTER statement, include the IGNORE keyword. Like so

```
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (column);
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table_name
```

This will drop all the duplicate rows. As an added benefit, future INSERTs that are duplicates will error out. As always, you may want to take a backup before running something like this...

Comment: I believe this will drop all but one of the lines with dups. Questioner wanted all rows that contain dups to be deleted

Comment: don't comment anything @RiggsFolly first check this. i suggest only questioner.